What is the recommended approach for handling SMTP mail sending failures using JavaMailSender?
We have implemented SMTP email sending functionality in our service using JavaMailSender. Recently, there was an internal error on the SMTP server, causing our service to be unable to send emails for a period of time. Fortunately, critical business logic is separated from the email sending logic, so there was no severe impact on our service. We identified errors occurring in the javamailsender.send() part through try-catch blocks.
In case the SMTP server goes down or errors occur related to authentication, are there any recommended approaches to handle these situations? Currently, we are considering logging the error data into a database for monitoring purposes and implementing logic to retry failed email sends.
Is there any alternative approach besides this method that we could consider?
If you have any good ideas on how to handle post-processing when email sending fails due to SMTP server issues, please share. Thank you.
Here are three methods I'm currently considering:

Implementing retry logic (with a limited number of attempts and increasing time intervals).
Setting up a backup SMTP server to use in case of failures.
Using a message queue or database to store unsent messages for retrying.


Please post the code you have so far.
